# Printing a hardcopy of a BizTalk Orchestration

Tags: c#, printing, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

I want to print my orchestration in a BizTalk 2010 solution. During the meeting, hard copy is more helpful for understanding, so I want to print my orchestration.

Do you have any idea for this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Altough never tried myself, it might work when printing the outline of an orchestration using the BizTalk Documenter (http://biztalk2010autodc.codeplex.com/). This can document your orchestration on PDF/CHM file which can be printed. However, if your orchestration is complex, you might have issues with readability.

You can also just print from Visual Studio when you have your orchestration opened. Just click File > Print.
Sometimes it's just that simple. You'll have to do some puzzling though :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried biztalk documenter but getting this error while start "Generate Documentation", **failed to enable constraints,One or more row contain values violating nun-null, uniqueue, or foreign-key constraints**

Comment: @shafak Do you have the same issue when you're browsing in the Admin Console?

Comment: Sory Pieter but i cant understanding you, what does it mean browsing in the Admin Console?

Comment: @shafak Do you get a similar error while browsing the same application in the BizTalk Admin Console when viewing RL, SP, etc... ?
If this is the case: there might be something wrong with your BizTalk database.

The error you describe might also indicate a problem with the Documenter itself as well, in that case I'm unable to help you I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the BizTalk Server 2013 Documenter on [Codeplex](https://biztalk2013documenter.codeplex.com/releases)  ...

**And yes, I do mean 2013** ... check the downloads page, it also has a variant for 2006 to 2010